# Probability exponential cdf verification question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

If $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ are mutually independent exponential($\lambda$) random variables, what is the $96$th percentile of $3\min\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$?

The answer I got is $\frac{-1.44}{\lambda}$ and I'm not sure if that makes sense or not... Could somebody please verify or discredit this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"exponential($\lambda$)" is ambiguous since sometimes it means the density is proportional to $e^{-\lambda x}$ and sometimes it means it's proportional to $e^{-x/\lambda}$.

Assuming the former is meant, we have $\Pr(X_1>x) = e^{-\lambda x}$ and
$$
\Pr(\min>x)=\Pr(X_1>x\ \&\ X_2>x\ \&\ X_3>x) = \Big(\Pr(X_1>x)\Big)^3 = \Big(e^{-\lambda x}\Big)^3 = e^{-3\lambda x}
$$
So 
$$
e^{-3\lambda x} = 0.04 \iff x = \frac{\log0.04}{-3\lambda} = \frac{\log 25}{3\lambda}.
$$
(Note $1/0.04=25$.  The natural logarithm of $25$ is somewhat more than $3$, so the bottom line is somewhat more than $1/\lambda$.)

**PS:** I neglected the $3$, so let's deal with that.
$$
\Pr(3\min>x) = \Pr(\min>x/3),
$$
so just put $x/3$ in place of $x$ in what was done above:
$$
\Pr(\min>x/3) = \Big(e^{-\lambda x/3}\Big)^3 = e^{-\lambda x}.
$$
So we end up with $\dfrac{\log 25}{\lambda}$.

Comment: That follows for $\min\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$, but what about $3\min\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$?
(Might be a dumb question, but I'm not sure what holds algebraically in probability)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the $3$, but I've added a postscript dealing with it.